Do images respect flex box rules?
In this example I would expect the image to be 80 pixels tall. I've tested in Firefox, Chrome and Safari and the image is much larger. Why is this?


.imagepluslabel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100px;
}

img {
  flex: 1;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.label {
  flex-basis: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
<div class="imagepluslabel">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Phone Image">
  <div class="label">label</div>
</div>




pls use code snippet tools to create a working example.

Sure. But flex:1 is not a max-height setting... An image will grow to it's natural height unless constrained somehow.
